# Module Tab & Navigation tab Interaction

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, accessibility, psychology, experience

I am currently working on an enterprise website with loads of different views/content.

I have chosen **tabs** as a navigation and each tab has a new view in it .On top of this, i have grouped all these tabs into **modules** and chose **module tabs** for navigation.

Check the first image for reference

[image]

The problem that I am facing here is the arrows on top seems functional on secondary tabs but in primary when arrows are used user misses context as top-level tabs move away.

and another option I tried was putting more at the end of top-level tabs.

Check the first image for reference

[image]

but I am not sure of how this interaction would look

example - when the user selects tab 9 from the drop-down how will user go back to tab 1

[image]

So arrow is necessary here again and it is will be a mix of option 1 and 2 which seems wrong I think.

**Let me know if this has any other solutions.**

**This is how it looks in site** 
[image]

Comment: Tab overload! I would avoid those tab like buttons for the "Layout" section. Icons could easily work here and there are icons available for such options. Just a thought.

Comment: Can the subcategories be set in multiple rows instead? Or are there subcategories below those tabs as well? It feels like the core of the problem is bad categorization, really. Is there a way to break you navigation down into more digestible chunks? Even if this means adding more levels?

Answer (score 3):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCforU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The same question had been already raised earlier. What about handling primary modules as horizontal tabs and secondary modules as vertical tabs?

I have added a very rough mockup just to convey the idea. From your design, the user will have to click on a more button to view the remaining primary modules. So,if the user don't have to shift between primary modules very frequently, you could give the option for user to set an initial context for primary modules and allow the user to shift between the secondary modules.

NB: The way to select of primary module in the mockup may not be the correct option. I just put it up to convey the idea.

Comment: I would be happy to but as all the views take up a full page. I  cannot afford to use vertical space. This platform I am working on is a data platform hence every pixel is important for me.

Comment: Have you made a design for a concept with a sidebar? It might not be as unfeasible as you think, and if it is, you have solid evidence it cannot be done (for your stakeholders). Currently the navigation is heavily cluttered and confusing, so sacrificing some space for navigation seems like a priority.

Comment: Is it mandatory to show the primary module all the time? Will the user switch between the modules frequently?

Comment: Yes, all all the information is almost related and all modules are core features

Comment: I was hoping if the shifting between the primary tabs is not often, you could limit the selection of primary modules to one at a time using a filter or a drop-down at the top and hence the secondary modules will behave as a context driven (based on the primary module selected)

Comment: I couldn't picture what you said can u please make a wireframe and send it . it will be very helpful

Comment: But i lose context on all the main module elements , it gets hidden in that drop down

Answer (score 1):

**Vertical Navigation**

Vertical (a.k.a. “Sidebar”) navigation is a way of showing a persistent site or application structure along one side of the product.

Unlike tabs, vertical navigation is appropriate when the number of categories is not small, or is user-customizable (such as folders or tags in an email client). It is considered a “safe” navigation pattern because it is familiar, flexible, and doesn’t take up much space. It is often used when there is no other obvious choice.

**In your case**

You could try using some of the vertical space with "Tabs" and Horizontal Space with "Sub Tabs". Much like the image attached below.[image: vertical space with "Tabs" and Horizontal Space with "Sub Tabs"]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're so adamant on tabs. When you have multiple layers of navigation tabs become confusing, frustrating and difficult to navigate.

I've recently been looking into navigation for mega sites and this nifty example of a top navigation bar came up in my research. https://www.fold3.com/image/10985207

It doesn't take much screen space when the user is browsing the selected page and neatly folds out when the user wants to navigate.

I know that maybe this isn't a direct answer to your problem but I hope it inspires a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain the down vote please?

Answer (score 0):

...Since I am also working on complex dashboards and have encountered the same issue several times, I turned up into turning tab elements into vertically collapsed nested dropdown elements.

edit: About your concern that you need to use every pixel available - when users need to navigate, they don't really care about what's on the current screen; they just want to get there easily. No-one is going to play with your menus (although many of us would like them to!), they just need of an intuitive way to navigate to the page their want. Nothing more straightforward that what they are already used to (and I proposed above).. nested dropdowns.

edit2: I well deserve the downvote, but I didn't get what you asked for before you asked again.

Check this out. If you remove the 'tab' style on the top menu, then, even scrolling out wouldn't keep you 'out of context', would make more sense that having a 'tab style' being out of view.

[image]

Comment: No idea why the downvote, all I suggested was to style the tabs as nested dropdowns in the mobile version...oh, well... I'll deal with it :)

Comment: I also didn't understand why the downvoting, so have one on the house. I think this problem would be avoided with proper page grouping and with prioritization sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could minimize the tabs furthest from the selected tad.

initial

```
|*tab 1*|tab 2|tab 3|tab 4|tab 5|tab 6|t.|t.|t.|
```

tab 5 selected

```
|t.|t.|tab 3|tab 4|*tab 5*|tab 6|tab 9|tab 8|t.|
```